# jQuery - Resize <body> to page width. (zoom works, how can I make it shrink too?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been using this site as a resource while I learn a bit of jQuery. My skill level is mostly integrating and modifying other peoples code. So far so good.
I have a problem, and signed up so I could post a question.

Basically, I have a site that is designed for a 1280px width. I am using jQuerytools' "tabs" and "scrollable" plugins to have a 4000px+ horizontal image scroll with content. 
Of course on a 1080p screen, the "scrollable" pane was not reaching both sides of the screen. 
My solution was a script I found to zoom the page if the width was larger than 1280px.

Here is the code.

```
$().ready(function() {
var currentWidth = $(document.body).width();
var targetWidth = 1280; // experiment for your self
var scrollWidth = 10; // need to make it dynamic
// if the screen is not bigger than the target, then don't mess with zooming
if (currentWidth > targetWidth) {
  if (typeof document.body.style.zoom != "undefined")
    document.body.style.zoom = currentWidth / targetWidth;
  else if (typeof document.body.style.MozTransform != "undefined") {
    document.body.style.MozTransformOrigin = "left top";
    document.body.style.MozTransform = 'scale(' + currentWidth / targetWidth + ')';
  }
  else if (typeof document.body.style.WebkitTransform != "undefined")
    document.body.style.WebkitTransform = 'scale(' + currentWidth / targetWidth + ')';

  $(document.body).width(targetWidth - scrollWidth);}})
```

This works great, but I cannot figure out how to make it shrink if the body is less than 1280px.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yo might want to look into css media-queries. Also, what is this `$().ready(function()`?

Comment: I don't know. It is someone else's code. I copy and pasted it, it worked, so I figured it was right. Should be document.ready?

Comment: @elclans Thank you, css media-queries looks like a much more elegant solution.

Comment: Are you using background-images? If so the CSS3 background-size property can allow images to scale to the full size of their container. - http://www.css3.info/preview/background-size/

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things, jquery has two ways I know of of firing on the document ready object, one is

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
```

the other shorthand I am familiar with is

```
$(function(){
```

It is not recommended to use the `$().ready` syntax. Please check the jquery documentation http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Also, you have no closing semicolon at the end of your code. You would do well with a quick briefing on jquery syntax at codeacademy. I have found that if one bit of jquery code has bad syntax, the DOM will not load completely.